# Three.js camera rotation change doesn't work

Tags: three.js

I can't set camera rotation.

Tried:

`camera.rotation.set(10,10,10);`

`camera.rotation.x = 10;`

But none of those work... like it wouldn't totally affect camera (old values stay unchanged)

Setting `camera.rotationAutoUpdate = false;` doesn't change anything...

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried lookAt ?

Comment: That can have different reasons. Maybe you got the wrong camera, or you don't render afterwards, or the rotation of your camera is overriden by regular updates, etc. For determining the reason why'd have to have a jsfiddle or any type of source.

Comment: The problem was that I used `THREE.TrackballControls` ... simple `controls.reset();` worked :-)

Comment: similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16525043/reset-camera-using-orbitcontrols-js

Answer (score 0):

You should call `camera.updateProjectionMatrix();` whenever you change camera's properties

Answer (score 0):

It could be if you are using `OrbitControls` it overwrites the camera, specifically when calling `controls.update`.

But it looks like three.js doesn't need you to call it anymore as long as you instantiated it `const controls = new OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);` it will work fine and won't interfere with the camera.

[source](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PcHW02QA5d4)